# Access Azure Subscriptions under Account A using Account/Group from AAD under Account B

Tags: active-directory, azure, entra-id

We have an Azure Account with many subscriptions ("Account A"). We bought another company who has an Azure account with multiple subscriptions ("Account B"). Does anyone know if we can have accounts and groups from Account A AD used for permissioning subscriptions under Account B? I know about Guest Accounts; this doesn't work with groups. Some people have used the term "Mounting Account A's AD in Account B's Account" and those people seem fairly adamant about it being a thing, but I've never found anything on it. Is this possible? Anyone done it before?

Answer (score 1):

As I known , there is nothing about "Mounting Account A's AD in Account B's Account" of Azure AD. For your Scenario, the only method is Azure AD B2B. Although inviting guest users doesn't work for Groups, you still need to invite each users in that group.

**Solution:**

You can **bulk-invite** external users to an organization from email addresses that you have stored in a .CSV file.

**NOTE:**

Before starting bulk-invite , you'd better grant privileges to a guest user and then add users from the partner to your organization **without needing invitations** to be redeemed

So, the main steps are folloing:

1. A user in the A organization invites one user from the B organization as Guest.
2. The admin in the A organization sets up policies that allow that invited user to identify and add other users from the B organization.
3. Bulk-invite external users to an organization from email addresses that you have stored in a .CSV file.

You can see more details about Bulik-invite external users in [this document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-b2b-code-samples).

Additional, after inviting all users , you can create a group for them and assign your subscription access to that group.

Comment: Hi,@GeneLaisne. If this answer is helpful to you please mark it as answer so that we can help more people. Thanks!